# Cannot initialize pyarrow with cpp libraries

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow

How do I install pyarrow so that it uses cpp or cython code?

I cannot use conda in my project (like documentation suggests)

```
pa.get_include()
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/include'
pa.get_libraries()
['arrow', 'arrow_python']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to call `pa.create_library_symlinks()` before you start using the cpp libraries.

See the [doc](http://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/extending.html?highlight=create_library_symlinks#building-extensions-against-pypi-wheels).

This was introduced recently to make the package smaller, see this [blog post](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2020/07/29/cpp-build-simplification/)